# Why does this code taking input of string and outputting an int not work? Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

I thought this would be a neat way of structuring a picker method but the output is not going to the first two if statements and only outputs the last

```
    public int myPickerMethod(){

        System.out.println("please select from the options ");
        System.out.println("please select 1 for option 1 ");
        System.out.println("please select 2 please select 2 for option 2");
        String input = keyboard.readLine();
        System.out.println("input = " + input);     

        if(input=="1"){

                return 1;
        }
        else if(input=="2"){
            return 2;
        }
        else{
            return 42;
        }
   }
```

Here is my result from the terminal:

```
   please select from the options 
   please select 1 for option 1 
   please select 2 please select 2 for option 2
   1
   input = 1
   response = 42
```

Same goes if I put 2 in. the "response" print statement is the output from the method from a print statement in the main class.

I have not tried this way before but I figured it should work. I don't really get why it isn't. Anyone able to clear this up? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: why'd he get down votes?

Comment: I would not have made the connection between that thread and mine. Firstly, you would have to know the solution already to know the two are connected. Secondly that is a String array not a String.

Comment: @johnny: I didn't understand it too...

Comment: @davidbuzatto I will keep my mouth closed, but I have a theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For testing Object (non-primitive type) equality, use `Object.equals()`.

```
if(input.equals("1")) {

    return 1;
}
```

The `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal. A test for reference equality is done within the `String.equals() method`, among other checks. Below is the Java source for the `String.equals()` method:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
     if (this == anObject) {      // Reference equality
         return true;
     }
     if (anObject instanceof String) {
         String anotherString = (String)anObject;
         int n = count;
         if (n == anotherString.count) {  // Are the strings the same size?
             char v1[] = value;
             char v2[] = anotherString.value;
             int i = offset;
             int j = anotherString.offset;
             while (n-- != 0) {
                 if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])        // Compare each character
                     return false;
             }
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for clarifying why it was. I was starting to suspect it might be something to do with the String not being primative.

Answer (score 9):

In Java you need to compare Strings using the equals method:

```
if ( input.equals("1") ) {
    // do something...
}
```

Since Java 7, you can use Strings in switch statements too:

```
switch ( input ) {

    case "1":
        // do something...
        break;

    case "2":
        // do something...
        break;

}
```

**Edit:** Complementing my answer, here is an example of a class that uses switch with strings and the disassembled code of the class (using javap -c) and why it works (labels 8 and 11).

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String str = "foo";

        switch ( str ) {

            case "foo":
                System.out.println( "Foo!!!" );
                break;

            case "bar":
                System.out.println( "Bar!!!" );
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println( "Neither Foo nor Bar :(" );
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

**Disassembled Foo.class code:**

```
Compiled from "Foo.java"
public class Foo {
  public Foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String foo
       2: astore_1      
       3: aload_1       
       4: astore_2      
       5: iconst_m1     
       6: istore_3      
       7: aload_2       
       8: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.hashCode:()I  << hashCode here! (I wrote this!)
      11: lookupswitch  { // 2

                 97299: 50                  // 97299: hashCode of "bar" (I wrote this!)

                101574: 36                  // 101574: hashCode of "foo" (I wrote this!) (yep, they where swaped. the lesser hashCode first)
               default: 61
          }
      36: aload_2       
      37: ldc           #2                  // String foo
      39: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      42: ifeq          61
      45: iconst_0      
      46: istore_3      
      47: goto          61
      50: aload_2       
      51: ldc           #5                  // String bar
      53: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      56: ifeq          61
      59: iconst_1      
      60: istore_3      
      61: iload_3       
      62: lookupswitch  { // 2

                     0: 88

                     1: 99
               default: 110
          }
      88: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      91: ldc           #7                  // String Foo!!!
      93: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      96: goto          118
      99: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     102: ldc           #9                  // String Bar!!!
     104: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     107: goto          118
     110: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     113: ldc           #10                 // String Neither Foo nor Bar :(
     115: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     118: return        
}
```

One interesting thing is that another switch is created (label 62) with integers and is it which do the "real work".

Comment: +1 for the Java 7 note. I didn't know. What happens under the hood? `equals` of hashing. I think hashing because, switch historically wants an `int`.

Comment: Yep, the compiler changes the switch, calling the hashCode method in the switch and cases values :D

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: I complemented my answer with some disassembled code. Take a look!

Comment: I never fully understood the output of javap, but am I right that it first uses a hashCode, used in the first switch, and then rechecks for hashcollisions with `equals`, to be 100% sure that the strings are equal. And finally uses the output of the double check in the second switch.

Answer (score 5):

**1.** Use `.equals` to compare `Objects` in java, and `String` is an **Object in Java**.

**eg:**
    `if(input.equals("1"))`

**2.** This is **optional**, but it will be also good, if you try to use Scanner class.

**eg:**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine();
```

**3.** Its will be also advisable to use `switch` statement **instead of** `if-else` ladder, if switch is used using `String` then **you must have** `jdk 1.7 or above`, **else if you are using jdk version less than** `1.7`, then you can **convert the String to character and then use it in switch.**

Comment: Ya thats right.... i thought that will be quite obvious as the current version in the market is Jdk 1.7u5, and Java 8 is around the corner...... Well then too i have added it... Thanks...

Comment: +1 for converting the string to a char for switch use.

Answer (score 3):

Don't compare value of Strings (or any Objects) by `==`. Use `equals` method like `if(input.equals("1"))`.

`==` is used to check if references contains same object for example

```
Integer i1=new Integer(1);
Integer i2=new Integer(1);
Integer i3=i1;
//checking references
System.out.println(i1==i2);//false
System.out.println(i1==i3);//true

//checking values
System.out.println(i1.equals(i2));//true
System.out.println(i1.equals(i3));//true
```

Answer (score 3):

Object comparison should be [`.equals`](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2003/04/how_equals_work.html) not `==` and `String` is an object.

input=="1" should be input.equals("1")

**EDIT**  Following always works even though you use `==`because they are literals and java allocates same memory location.

```
 String s ="Hi";
 String s1= "Hi";

 if(s==s1)
 {
     System.out.println("Yes they are same");
 }
```

But, when we are reading two separate strings `(new String())`, unless you override `equals` and `hashcode`, equality condition may not be satisfied. Read above link for more details.

Comment: thanks that worked. Why is that though? I have found it worked before I tried to use with a string.

Comment: When you are comparing on same reference (or) String literals it may work, but in this case they are two separate new strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals` method....

```
public int myPickerMethod(){

    System.out.println("please select from the options ");
    System.out.println("please select 1 for option 1 ");
    System.out.println("please select 2 please select 2 for option 2");
    String input = keyboard.readLine();
    System.out.println("input = " + input);     

    if(input.equals("1")){

            return 1;
    }
    else if(input.equals("2")){
        return 2;
    }
    else{
        return 42;
    }
```

}

Comment: ah thanks I got it now. +1 though for answering fully. Do you know why it is so that the use of '==' did not work?

Comment: "==" compares object reference values where "equals()" compares object contents....